# How to find derivative for $g(x)=\int^{x}_{1}[(f(t))^2-t^2]dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

How to find derivative for $g(x)=\int^{x}_{1}[(f(t))^2-t^2]dt$

In my opinion $g'(x)=(f(x))^2-x^2$ and $g'(x)=0$ when $(f(x))^2=x^2$. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, correct application of the fundamental theorem of calculus.